# Adding a row to matrix using matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, syntax

I have a matrix 'A' whose dimension change every time when i run the code. The problem is i have to insert 6 zeros after the last row of matrix A and at last 6 column positions.

For example A(300,168) dimension matrix, now i have to increase it dimension like this A(301,168). 1 row increased by inserting zeros at last 6 column which starts from 164 to 168.
I am having difficulty in finding the correct syntax. 
Here is what i am trying

```
[m, n] = size(A);

A = [A; zeros(m+1, n-5:n, 6)];
```

Comment: And what do you plan to have in the first 163 columns ? In an array, you cannot add row only to selected columns, it has to be a full row. Your `zeros(..,..,..)` statement is incompatible for concatenation with a 2D array `A`. If you want to add a full row of zeros, use `A=[A;zeros(1,n)];`. If you want the added row to be different you'll have to explain what value to use for the first 163 column...

Comment: Okay i got your point. If could be the syntax if i can insert 6 values in last 6 columns and remaining with zeros ?

Comment: `A=[A ; [zeros(1,n-6) v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6]];` for example. There are other ways. Read the article : [Matrix Indexing in MATLAB](http://mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html). That is quite a prerequisite to handle arrays in Matlab.

Comment: I don't understand your question, if you insert zeros to the last 6 columns, what happens to the other columns? Matlab will automatically pad zeros so you would end up with a row of zeros.

Comment: Thanks @Hoki my problem is solved.

Comment: Yes @Daniel i understand what you are trying to say. Thanks